# How to speed up mysql multiple table updation from main table

Tags: mysql

This time I again come up with another problem, I have some tables, in which table1 is process table which contains some useful information like process id, date etc, what I need to do is I have to update process_id and process_date from table1 to table2, table3 etc when serial number is same, table1 is small in size maximum around 50k, but other tables are very big like 300k,700k rows, I want to speed up updation, please let me know if there is any good way

so far I have tried like this, being a beginner I am bit confused also that I may be wrong, there might be some good way...hope you guys can understand me.

```
  update table2 t2,table1 t1 
  set 
    t2.process_id   = t1.process.id,
    t2.process_date = t1.process_date
  where 
    t1.serial = t2.serial 


  mysql> select count(*) from table1;
  +----------+
  | count(*) |
  +----------+
  |    27610 |
  +----------+
  1 row in set (0.13 sec)

  mysql> select count(*) from table2;
  +----------+
  | count(*) |
  +----------+
  |    321827 |
  +----------+
  1 row in set (0.18 sec)
```

Comment: Is `serial` indexed in both tables? That would save you a lot of time.

Comment: serial is column available in both table, sir please let me know the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns used to link tables should be indexed to improve performance:

```
CREATE INDEX table1_serial ON table1 (serial);
CREATE INDEX table2_serial ON table2 (serial);
```

This will allow MySQL to rapidly create the relation between the tables when you try to update them based on `WHERE t1.serial = t2.serial`.